# Getting Objects from a bucket in AWS S3 using Blazor Wasm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, blazor, blazor-webassembly, bucket

I am trying to read objects in an AWS S3 bucket using Blazor WASM. But i am getting the following error:

> Access to fetch at 'an AWS url' from origin 'my app URL'  has been
> blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass
> access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
> present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your
> needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with
> CORS disabled.

```
public async Task<List<string>> ListBucketContentsAsync()
    {
        var config = new AmazonS3Config
            {
                RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1,
                UseAlternateUserAgentHeader = true
            };

        var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client("MYKEY", "MYSECRET", config);

        var bucketObjectResponse = await s3Client.ListObjectsV2Async(new ListObjectsV2Request
            {
                BucketName = "MYBUCKETNAME"
            });

        var bucketObjectNames = bucketObjectResponse.S3Objects.Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
        return bucketObjectNames;
    }
```

I also allowed CORS in my server. Why do I still get the CORS policy error?

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(opts);
builder.Services.AddCors();
app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials());
```